# Which profession has the longest ranged attack?

Tags: guild-wars-2

According to [this site](http://www.guildwarsinsider.com/professions-weapon-ranges/), warriors and mesmers have the longest ranged attacks, but this doesn't take into account traits which can increase range.

**If traits are considered, which profession has the longest maximum range on an attack?**

Comment: Mesmer range is wrong. The range is 1200, and the range of the phantasm it summons is 1700 (which is irrelevant in this case, since you need to be in range to summon it in the first place)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ranger does.

A few longbow attacks are already 1200 range, and the [Eagle Eye](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Eagle_Eye) trait expands that by 25%, to 1500 even.

Comment: If you think this answer is in error, please let me know. Downvotes without comments do not help get better answers on the site.

Comment: Yeah, if the GW2 wiki page on [Range](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Range) is correct, then the Ranger's is currently the longest.

Comment: Warrior Kill Shot also has a range of 1500.

Answer (score 1):

The Engineer can extend grenade range to 1500 also.  And since they are all AOE, are most useful in WVW.